# Test case using SpringJunitRunner

Tags: spring, junit, jersey

I want to write junit test case for the below code with springJunitRunner.
the below piece of code is one service in a class.

```
@Component
@Path(/techStack)
public class TechStackResource {



@Autowired
  private transient TechStackService techStackService;

@GET
 @Path("/{id}")
 @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
  public Response getTechStackById(final @PathParam("id") Integer technicalstackid) {
    final TechStackResponse response = new TechStackResponse();
    int statusCode = Constants.HTTP_STATUS_OK_200;
    try {
      TechStackModel techStackModel = techStackService.findObjectById(technicalstackid);
      response.setGetTechStackDetails(GetTechStackDetails.newBuilder().technicalStack(techStackModel).build());

      if (techStackModel == null) {
        statusCode = Constants.HTTP_STATUS_ERROR_404;
      }

    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException erde) {

    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOGGER.error("Exception occured in TechStackResource.getTechStackById(technicalstackid) ", e);
      throw new APMRestException(
          "Exception while executing TechStackResource.getTechStackById(technicalstackid) ",
          Constants.UNKNOW_ERROR, e);
    }
    return Response.status(statusCode).entity(response).build();
  }
}
```

the configuration in web.xml for servlet is

```
<servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
```

Comment: what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using *Jersey* as well as *Spring*, you can use the `SpringJunitRunner` only to wire-up `TechStackResource` with its dependency `TechStackService`.

In order to test your REST handler method `getTestStackById`, you could go the POJO approach and invoke it directly. Alternatively, you can use Jersey's own MockWeb environment. To find out more about this, I recommend looking at the Jersey example sources, e.g. [HelloWorld](https://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/content/trunk/jersey/samples/helloworld/src/test/java/com/sun/jersey/samples/helloworld/MainTest.java?rev=5954).